# ¿Cómo hacer un Update a un campo recién creado?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Intento agregar una columna a una tabla "Persona" y posteriormente agregar valores a esa misma tabla desde el mismso SCRIPT el problema radica en que no reconoce el campo que acabo de agregar, imagino que es por la forma en que se ejecuta la transacción y como aun no termina de ejecutar el script pues dicho campo no existe.  ¿Alguna idea para lograrlo?

Dejo mi script

La tabla persona solo tiene  los campos

- ID
- Nombre
- Apellido

Dicha tabla  ya cuenta con un par de registros  ejemplo

- ID:1   Nombre: Luis     Apellido: López
- ID:2   Nombre: Rafael   Apellido:García

Intento agregar el campo Dirección y  a su vez  establecer su valor en el registro de Luis por ejemplo

```
ALTER TABLE Persona
    ADD Direccion VARCHAR(15);
```

Inmediatamente de eso necesito ingresar valores en ese campo

```
UPDATE Persona set Direccion = 'Calle 3 poniente' WHERE ID = 1
```

El problema es que SQL me marca como invalido el campo Dirección. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Prueba agregar un `GO;` despues del `ALTER`.

Comment: mysql, mssql? por lo general alter y update tienen que ir en dos pasos (al cambiar la tabla pueden cambiar indices, o hay que calcular el default de la nueva columna para todos los registros)

Comment: @PatricioMoracho el GO ha funcionado de maravilla muchas gracias.

Comment: @aloMalbarez Gracias por el dato

Comment: [Te pueden votar negativamente porque tu pregunta no incluye los detalles de la excepción.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2877/), igual creo quedeberías poner que motor de base de datos usas, puede variar mucho la respuesta si usas postgresql, cassandra, mongo, Oracle, MySQL, Access, etc

Comment: "Calle 3 poniente" son 16 caracteres...

Answer (score 2):

Lo que ocurre es que estás enviando al motor, el siguiente lote de sentencias:

```
ALTER TABLE Persona
    ADD Direccion VARCHAR(15);

UPDATE Persona set Direccion = 'Calle 3 poniente' WHERE ID = 1;
```

La interpretación (no ejecución) que hace el motor es por el lote completo, vale decir que en el momento en que haces el `UPDATE`, la tabla `Persona` no ha sido modificada físicamente aún, de ahí que la interpretación o compilación del lote de sentencias, falle.

En SQL server existe el comando [`GO`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-2017) que NO es un comando de Transact-SQL sino una instrucción para las herramientas `sqlcmd`, `osql` y el editor de `SQL Server Management` (incluye también al `isqlw`) el cual se interpreta como una señal para ejecutar el último lote de clausulas SQL enviadas.

Con este comando, podrías hacer

```
ALTER TABLE Persona
    ADD Direccion VARCHAR(15);
GO;

UPDATE Persona set Direccion = 'Calle 3 poniente' WHERE ID = 1;
GO;
```

Lo cual le señalará al motor que interprete y ejecute el `ALTER` y luego recién haga el l `UPDATE`, de esta forma, al momento de la ejecución del segundo lote, la tabla ya estará modificada.

Comentarios adicionales:

- Al no ser un comando Transact, no puede usarse (tampoco tiene sentido) dentro de stored procedures, funciones o triggers.
- Como curiosidad, en las herramientas mencionadas es posible modificar el nombre de este comando

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: se podría armar un "inline stored procedure" para que el update sea diferido?

Comment: @aloMalbarez, no se si te entiendo del todo lo que preguntas, lo que te puedo decir, que el problema pasa por la compilación de la sentencia `UPDATE Persona set Direccion = 'Calle 3 poniente' WHERE ID = 1;` no por la ejecución de la misma. Si lo que buscas es crear un `sp` con esta sentencia para ejecutarlo luego, sigues con el mismo problema, cuando creas el `sp`, se "compila" en ese momento,  la tabla ya debería estar modificada para que no de error el `create` del `sp`.

Comment: pensaba en un `ALTER ...` seguido de un `EXECUTE sp_executesql N'UPDATE ...'`; se compila todo junto, o el exec difiere la ejecución?

Comment: Ahora si.. Si, con `sp_executesql` podrías, por que implícitamente es un lote de ejecución distinto al del `ALTER`.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto:

```
ALTER TABLE Persona
    ADD Direccion VARCHAR(15);

EXEC(N'UPDATE Persona set Direccion = ''Calle 3 poniente'' WHERE ID = 1');
```

Observación: también se tiene que corregir el tamaño del campo porque se está intentando actualizar un valor de 16 caracteres en un campo que soporta 15 caracteres.